# Rails don't save if duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a somewhat complex Rails model setup that I'll try to simplify as much as possible. The goal of this setup is to be able to have objects (`Person`, `Pet`) that are long-lived, but with relationships between them changing each year via `TemporalLink`. Basically, I have these models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TemporalObj

  has_many :pet_links, class_name: "PetOwnerLink"
  has_many :pets, through: :pet_links
end

class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TemporalObj

  has_many :owner_links, class_name: "PetOwnerLink"
  has_many :owners, through: :owner_links
end

class PetOwnerLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TemporalLink

  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :pet
end
```

and these concerns:

```
module TemporalLink
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Everything that extends TemporalLink must have a `year` attribute.
end

module TemporalObj
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Everything that extends TemporalObj must have a find_existing() method.

  ####################
  # Here be dragons! #
  ####################
end
```

The desired behavior is:

- When creating a `TemporalObj` (`Pet`, `Person`):

  1) Check to see if there is an existing one, based on certain conditions, with `find_existing()`.

  2) If an existing duplicate is found, don't perform the create but still perform necessary creations to associated objects. (**This seems to be the tricky part.**)

  3) If no duplicate is found, perform the create.

  4) [Existing magic already auto-creates the necessary `TemporalLink` objects.]
- When destroying a `TemporalObj`:

  1) Check to see if the object exists in more than one year. (This is simpler in actuality than in this example.)

  2) If the object exists in only one year, destroy it and associated `TemporalLink`s.

  3) If the object exists in more than one year, just destroy one of the `TemporalLink`s.

My problem is I have uniqueness validations on many `TemporalObj`s, so when I try to create a new duplicate, the validation fails before I can perform any `around_create` magic. Any thoughts on how I can wrangle this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to JacobEvelyn's comment, this is what I did.

1. Created a custom validate like so

```
      def maintain_uniqueness
        matching_thing = Thing.find_by(criteria1: self.criteria1, criteria2: self.criteria2)
        if !!matching_thing
          self.created_at = matching_thing.created_at
          matching_thing.delete
        end
        true
      end
```

2. Added it to my validations

   ```
   validate :maintain_event_uniqueness
   ```
3. It worked.

Comment: Interesting approach. I don't like the idea of deleting the old object (it could have other associations that are now broken), but since this works for the example I gave and is much simpler than the solution I came up with (which does a pretty elaborate dance of overriding default Rails methods), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use Rails' built-in validations here.  What you've described is `validates_uniqueness_of`, which you can scope to include multiple columns.

For example:

```
class TeacherSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :teacher_id, scope: [:semester_id, :class_id]
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: I am using uniqueness validations. The issue is that I want a duplicate `Person` create in a new year (where year is a global concept) to simply add a linking object to the existing `Person`. I don't want the create to fail.